# Поиск значения php в json и вывод массива

Tags: php, json

В общем есть необходимость хранить данные сотрудников в виде json.
Их около 60.

Есть возможность ввести логин сотрудника, он в виде AAPetrov в json название массива совпадает с логином.

Нужно при вводе найти данные массива в json и вывести их из файла, привязав к переменным, которые последствии закрепятся в сессии.

Есть ли возможность сделать поиск, не преобразовав данные json в массив и далее уже в массиве найти?

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку JSON это текстовый формат, то наиболее очевидный вариант решения вашей задачи - поиск по текстовому контенту с использованием регулярных выражений с помощью этой функции https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php . Здесь главное правильно составить регулярное выражение.